# The specified module was not loaded 'PSWindowsUpdate'

Tags: ruby, powershell, import-module

***Description: I am running/executing powershell from a ruby script (.rb) file***

```
exec "powershell.exe Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate"
```

I downloaded the `PSWindowsUpdate` module from "[Windows Update PowerShell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc)" and copied the files to the following location:

```
%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

When I run the above I get the following error:

```
Z:\Desktop>ruby windows_patch.rb
Import-Module : The specified module 'PSWindowsUpdate' was not loaded because
no valid module file was found in any module directory.At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (PSWindowsUpdate:String) [I
   mport-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
   ands.ImportModuleCommand
```

However, when I run this via Powershell it runs fine and dandy.

I'm using:

- Windows 7 x64
- PowerShell v4
- Ruby v2.1.5

The result of `exec "powershell.exe ruby -e 'puts $:'"` is:

```
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/i386-msvcrt
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/i386-msvcrt
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/i386-mingw32
```

Comment: Try to `exec "powershell.exe ruby -e 'puts $:'"` which will print modules dirs accessible for dry `powershell`.

Comment: @mudasobwa added the result above

Comment: So unpack modules to any of known locations (e.g. to `C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby`)  rather than to `%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`. Ruby modules are not PS modules and vice versa.

Comment: @mudasobwa same exact error copied to both that location and to `C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0`

Comment: Oh, sorry, that’s me mixing things up. I have read the module description carefully and realized that `PSWindowsUpdate` is _PS module_, not ruby module. So the problem is that PS can’t find it. Please disregard my wrong advise to extract it into ruby modules dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran `powershell.exe $env:PSModulePath` which gave me:

> \vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\M
>   odules\

I then copied the folder to `C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`

I then got:

> Import-Module : The specified module 'PSWindowsUpdate' was not loaded because
>   no valid module file was found in any module directory.At line:1 char:39

Next, I then ran:

```
PS C:\Users\Justin.Schuhmann> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine

cmdlet Set-ExecutionPolicy at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ExecutionPolicy: Unrestricted

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

This solved the issue, I don't have a permanent solution yet as this is only temporary.  When setting